# Find $ \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}$ $\frac{1}{n^{3}-n}$

Tags: limits

Find:

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}-n}$$

I tried to resolve into partial fractions to see if there are some cancellations ,but that did not helped me .How do i do this ?Thanks

Comment: It is an infinite series so when you say limit as $n$ goes to infinity, it does not make any sense. Try partial fractions $\frac{1}{(n-1)n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{2}{n}\right)$ .. there will be cancellation.

Comment: i tried to do this ,but calculations didnot seem to happen

Comment: The $N^{th}$ partial sum $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{n^3-n} = \sum\limits_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{2}{n}\right) =\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{n+1}-\sum\limits_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{n}$ .. these $3$ summations do have common terms and they will cancel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $n^3 - n = n(n^2 - 1) = n(n-1)(n+1)$, $$\frac{1}{n^3 - n} = \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)} = \frac{1}{2n}\left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2(n-1)n} - \frac{1}{2n(n+1)}.$$ Now $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty 1/(n^3 - n)$ telescopes to $1/4$.

Answer (score 3):

We know that the series at hand is convergent absolutely, so we can safely play with the sum.

$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3 - n} = -\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n} + 0.5\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1} + 0.5\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n-1} = -\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n} + 0.5\sum_{i=3}^\infty\frac{1}{n} + 0.5\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} = -\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} + 1 + 0.5\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} - 0.5 - 0.25 + 0.5\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} = 1 - 0.75 = 0.25 = \frac{1}{4}$$.

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the limit is $\frac14$.