# Again quick questions of infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

These are series:

1.$\sum_{n=2}^{1000}\frac{2}{n^3-n}=\sum_{n=2}^{1000}\frac{1}{n-1}-\sum_{n=2}^{1000}\frac{2}{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{1000}\frac{1}{n+1}$.

2. $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n^3-n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n-1}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$

Both is to express the sum in different ways possibly. ¿But it's not the same? Which is correct, or is both is correct. ¿Should I factor to solve it? I don't have access to know it. Can I have help? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $ \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}$ $\frac{1}{n^{3}-n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140157/find-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n3-n)

Comment: $1$ and $2$ are both correct, but note that number $2$ can be written as a telescoping series: see the link in my other comment. To do it your way, you first have to prove that $\frac{2}{n^3-n}$ is absolutely convergent so that you know it is valid to rearrange the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{2}{n^3-n}=\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{1}{n-1}-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{2}{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{1}{n+1}$$

is true for all $k\ge2,k\in I$.

The result immediately follows after a quick [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)